# create filter with com.google.android.material.search.SearchView

Tags: java, android, material-design, searchview, searchbar

i followed the code in material components android :

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent``your text``">

  <!-- NestedScrollingChild goes here (NestedScrollView, RecyclerView, etc.). -->
  <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/searchbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <!-- Screen content goes here. -->
  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/searchbar_hint" />
  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

  <com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:hint="@string/searchbar_hint"
      app:layout_anchor="@id/search_bar">
    <!-- Search suggestions/results go here (ScrollView, RecyclerView, etc.). -->
  </com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

but i don't know how to filter with this searchview  , i only see instructions for androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
if i replace to androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView , when i click search bar , searchview doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code in Activity to show the SearchView and handle the backpress

```
    with(binding) {
        searchView
            .editText
            .setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
                searchBar.text = searchView.text
                searchView.hide()
                false
            }
    }
```

Alternatively, you can remove CoordinatorLayout and just connect it manually

```
searchView.setupWithSearchBar(searchBar)
```